# try finally in ant

Tags: ant

In my ant script, which runs the end-to-end integration tests, I first start a process, then do some other stuff, then run the tests, and then I need to make sure I kill the process. However, I need to make sure I kill the process even if something fails (so I need an equivalent to try finally). What is the recommended way of doing it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [Trycatch](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/trycatch.html) task from [Antcontrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/)

```
<trycatch property="error.message">
  <try>
    <echo message="Run integration test..."/>
    <echo message="Start process"/>
    <antcall target="launchTests"/>
  </try>

  <catch>
    <echo message="Integration test failed"/>
  </catch>

  <finally>
    <echo message="Kill the process"/>
    <exec executable="kill -9 ..."/>
  </finally>
</trycatch>
```

Comment: so my question is similar, if I have a `<get url="stuff"/>` task inside an ant target, and mid-download the user hits CTRL D, how can I delete the (partially) downloaded file? the `<finally>` block doesnt fire in the event of an interrupt signal, is there some other way to do it?